# Google Directory API non-admin accounts

Tags: spring, google-api, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have a setup where the users login through Google OAuth2.0 and hit the Google Directory API from Java Spring, where I then process data on that user. It is currently working only when I login with a Google admin account. I need this to work for all types of accounts. This is the URL I am hitting:

`https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/{userKey}`

Since it is working fine for admin users, is there any way to simply change this setup to also handle non-admin users? I am wondering if this requires something like a service account but I thought giving my application the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user` would be okay. Thanks

Comment: Hi! I posted an answer. I'm not sure whether you would be open to using a service account with domain-wide delegation. Let me know if that's the case and you would need more details on how to do that.

Comment: @Iamblichus Thanks for the response. I am going the service account route and am struggling to get authorization. I am not sure where it is breaking since it only return 401 unauthorized. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64283111/google-service-account-request-to-admin-sdk-api-401-not-authorized

Comment: Hi, I see you removed the question you referenced. I hope that's because you could solve this issue.

Comment: @Iamblichus yes, I solved it. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Non-admins cannot access this information:

Only admins with **Users** privilege (see privileges [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1219251#)) can perform actions like read Users properties. Non-admin accounts will recieve a 403 error with a message like this:

> Not Authorized to access this resource/api

Please take into account that Directory API is part of the Admin SDK, whose purpose is to manage domain resources, and can only be used by accounts with the corresponding admin privileges. In this sense, adding an additional scope won't change anything, considering that you are probably making a `GET` request (calling [Users: get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get)) and using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly`.

You could certainly use a service account that has been granted [domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) to impersonate an admin account and get rid of the login step altogether, but I'm not sure that's what you want to do.

#### Reference:

- [Admin privileges definitions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1219251#)
- [Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)